# Swift: Add Certificate Authority root certificate

Tags: ios, swift, ssl

We're attempting to follow the Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012884-CH1-SECSELFSIGNEDCERTS) for using your own certificate authority (CA):

> While a self-signed certificate is a reasonable approach during
>   development, there is a better way: create your own certificate
>   authority ... and have it issue a certificate for your test server.
>   You can then ... hard-wire your certificate authority's root
>   certificate into your app

I haven't been able to figure out how to hard wire the CA root cert using Swift.  The paper mentions an [approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012884-CH1-SECCUSTOMROOT) but I haven't been able to translate this into Swift code:

> 1. Get a copy of the remote peer's certificate ...
> 2. Get the server
>      certificate from the trust object (pass an index of 0 to
>      SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex)
> 3. Get the data for that server
>      certificate (SecCertificateCopyData)
> 4. Compare this to the certificate
>      data you got in step 1; if they match, you're talking to the correct
>      peer

How can you do this via Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pin the Public key of a certificate on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728636/how-to-pin-the-public-key-of-a-certificate-on-ios)

Comment: Difference is that ticket is about pinning the server SSL cert and this is about pinning the root CA cert..

Comment: Updated ticket to clarify objective/question