# Include certificate at the app

Tags: ios, macos, certificate

Is it possible to include a certificate at my app?
I want that anyone who download my app, would get my certificate as well.

If it's not possible - how can I attach the certificate for my users?

(iOS and MacOS)

Edit:
I need it for my VPN app, so I want the certificate to effect all other applications as well (Safari/Chrome)

Comment: does this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728636/how-to-pin-the-public-key-of-a-certificate-on-ios answer you question?

Comment: You may also need to add 'App Transport Security' exception if your server does not have a CA certified certificate. References :  : 1. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/6767 2. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706/

Comment: Thanks. I've edited the questions to better fit my needs. Don't know if it's possible..