# How to get the Public key in string format of a SSL certificate in ios

Tags: ios

I can get the public key of SSL certificate using SecTrustCopyPublicKey. But how can get the Public key in string format?

Comment: Please go through the below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728636/how-to-pin-the-public-key-of-a-certificate-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save public key ec curve name, you can use this function:

```
string public_key_ec_curve_name(X509 *x509)
{ 
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = X509_get_pubkey(x509);
    int key_type = EVP_PKEY_type(pkey->type);
    if (key_type == EVP_PKEY_EC)
    {
        cont EC_GROUP* group = EC_KEY_GET0_group(pkey->pkey.ec);
        int name = (group != NULL) ? EC_GROUP_get_curve_name(group) : 0;
        return name ? OBJ_nid2sn(name) : ";
    }
    return "";
}
```

it saves the public ec curve name in string format.